# why cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'integer'?

Tags: r, r-s4

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error:
    `Error in as.integer(tm) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'integer`?
I have been searching the internet but couldn't solve my problem.

> 

```
      library(Matrix)
     long <- file("C:\\New folder (5)\\inra.bin", "rb")
     A=readBin(long, integer(), size=2,n=67420*1, signed=F)
    ta<-t(A)
  lot <- file("C:\\New folder (5)\\lat.img", "rb")
    B=readBin(lot, integer(), size=2,n=67420*1, signed=F)
     tb<-t(B)
       wind <- file("C:\\Wind_WFD_200201.bin", "rb")
       C=readBin(wind, double(), size=4,n=67420*248, signed=TRUE)
        D<-matrix(C,nrow=248,ncol=67420)
         for(d in 1:31)
       {
        M <- Matrix(-9999, 360, 720)
         tm<-t(M)
       for(i in 1:67420)
       {
    tm[ta[i],tb[i]]= 10 * ((D[(d-1)*8+1,i] + D[(d-1)*8+2,i] +D[(d-1)*8+3,i] +D[(d- 1)*8+4,i] +D[(d-1)*8+5,i] +D[(d-1)*8+6,i] +D[(d-1)*8+7,i] +D[(d-1)*8+8,i] ) / 8)

 }###gooooooood
 to.write <- sprintf("C:\\Yar_%0d.bin", d)
 writeBin(as.integer(tm), size=2,to.write)
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [How to split and write to a file for S4 object in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095595/how-to-split-and-write-to-a-file-for-s4-object-in-r) .  In your case, it appears that `Matrix` returns an S4 object.  Try this:

```
foo <- Matrix(10,10,10)
slotnames(foo)
```

That may give a suggestion as to what you want to extract from your `tm` object.
But why are you using `Matrix` in the first place?  If you just use `base::matrix` this problem should disappear.
Edit: peeking at the documentation for package `Matrix,` it's clear that `as.integer` is not supported.  You probably would have to use `as(x,matrix)` first.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It has been solved.the above code will do calculations for one file in one folder.how can I tell R to continue to do the same thing with all the rest of files in that folder.

Comment: @SamiYemein Simplest way is to build a loop around your `long <- file("C:\\New folder (5)\\inra.bin", "rb")` statement, and build the folder path from an array of file names.   Something like `for (i in 1:10) { filename <- paste('C:\\New folder (5)\\','filearray[i]',sep='') ; long<-file(filename,'rb');{everything else} }`